# Make browser prompt for Open or Save while opening download link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using window.open to download a file.

```
 window.open(urlToDownload)
```

The download link which I am trying to open can either be a link to a content in **amazon s3 bucket** or directly a link to a file in my file system.

Currently the browser is immediately downloading the content. Instead I would like the browser to show a prompt message which says either to save or open the file. My file will be in .xlsx format.

Comment: so you want show the confirmation box for open or save right ?

Comment: Yeah, the confirmation box